# Read fails with spaces

Tags: php, readfile

I am very new to PHP and want to learn. I am trying to make a top-list for my server but I have a problem. My file is built like this:

"Name" "Kills"

```
"^0user1^7" "2"
"user2" "2"
"user3" "6"
"user with spaces" "91"
```

But if I want to read this with PHP it fails because the user has spaces.
That's the method I use to read the file:

```
$lines = file('top.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $line);
    echo isset($parts[0]) ? $parts[0] : 'N/A' ;
}
```

Maybe someone knows a better method, because this don't work very well :D.

Comment: You would need a regular expression to split your data lines but a better solution would be to use a database or a known / proven format like for example json.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Not sure how you created `top.txt`, but if possible, change that saving code and save as JSON. That would simplify and ease everything for you.

Comment: @Tomasz - There is no error in the code. Above code is exploding wrt to space, so last record will result in multiple values.

Comment: @jeroen - This Game doesn't support databases.

Comment: @MilanChheda top.txt is created by a script on my server. It saves the kills and player names. I can change the .txt to json but what's the positive effect of this?

Comment: JSON gives you key-value pairs. So you simply need to use `json_encode` and `json_decode`. No need of regex and explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need REGEX :-)

```
<?php

$lines = array(
    '"^0user1^7" "2"',
    '"user2" "2"',
    '"user3" "6"',
    '"user with spaces" "91"',
);

$regex = '#"(?<user>[a-zA-Z0-9\^\s]+)"\s"(?<num>\d+)"#';

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
    echo 'user = '.$matches['user'].', num = '.$matches['num']."\n";
}
```

In the regex, we have # delimiters, then look for stuff between quotes. Using (?PATTERN) gives you a named capture group. The first looks for letters etc, the second digits only.

See here to understand how the regex is matching!
https://regex101.com/r/023LlL/1/

See it here in action https://3v4l.org/qDVuf

Answer (score 0):

For your process this might help

```
$lines = file('top.txt');
$line = explode(PHP_EOL, $lines); // this will split file content line by line
foreach ($line as $key=>$value_line ) {
    echo str_replace(" ","",$value_line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, below is a simple example with JSON.

Assuming, you have stored records in JSON format:

```
$json = '{
 "user1": "12",
 "sad sad":"23"
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json);
foreach($decoded as $key => $value){
    echo 'Key: ' . $key . ' And value is ' . $value;
}
```

And here is the demo link: https://3v4l.org/ih1P7